# How do I increase the height of custom JPanel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to increase the height of a custom `JPanel` in a `JFrame`. I tried to use `pa.setSize(700,200)` but it does not change anything.

Here is the code:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello");
f.setResizable(true);
JPanel pa = new JPanel();
JButton btn = new JButton("Exit");

pa.setBackground(Color.red);
pa.setSize(700, 200);

f.setUndecorated(true);
f.getContentPane().add(pa, BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.setSize(new Dimension(700,700));
f.setLocation(500, 500);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1- Use a layout manager which would support the `preferredSize` property; 2- Override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `JPanel` to return a size you'd prefer;

Comment: hey its you again, thank you so much for the help bro. it works

Answer (score 0):

its very simple solution instead of pa.setsize() change it into pa.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,60));

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)